What are some cases where a drawn match went to the player w/ more black wins?
In some round robins or swiss, there are score tiebreakers based on black wins, like the 2022 Accentus Chess960 tournament. Never mind those. My question is for knockouts. Obviously this doesn't work for best-of-2. This has to be at least best-of-4.
I noticed in the 2016 & 2023 classical WCC's, the runner-ups Nepo & Sergey actually, 'won the classical portion' in having more black wins than, resp, Liren & Magnus.
For knockouts (except bo2), what are/were some major tournaments the drawn matches are/were decided, if possible, by that if a player had more black wins, then that player wins the match?


In the 1980 – 1981 candidates, where Lajos Portisch, as black, beat Boris Spassky in the 1st game of their initial classical set of games, and this was the only black win in their match! Quote:


When the quarterfinal between Portisch and Spassky was tied after 14 games, Portisch was declared the winner because he had won more games with Black.


I guess the quote is adjusting for set of course: There were more black wins in the initial classical set. Then for the rapid tiebreak set, the black wins were equal (both zero since all draws in the tiebreak set.

From chessgames.com - Portisch - Spassky Candidates Quarterfinal (1980) :


Unfortunately, this rule was not repeated for the STUPID quarter-finals of the 1983–1984 candidates re the 1984–1985 classical WCC!

From chessgames.com - Smyslov - Huebner Candidates Quarterfinal (1983) :

Robert Hübner, as black, beat Vasily Smyslov in the penultimate game of their classical games, and this was the only black win in all their classical & rapid games of the match! Like the 1980-1981 candidates case, all the rapid games were drawn.
Then Robert Hübner suffered worse than Nepo & Sergey : the 2nd tiebreak was roulette!
